# export ActiveX control from exe

Tags: c++, activex, controls, exe

I got one challenging task here.
We got one Dialog in exe file (made of C++), and now we want it to be an ActiveX control, so it could be loaded in C# .net form, However because of the complicated web of c++ header file, it's hard to pick up files to make a separate ActiveX dll.
So is that possible to export an activeX control from the exe file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

An ActiveX control is a nothing more than a DLL. Yes it is possible to export an activeX control from an exe file. A typical scenario is to put an Image (your ActiveX control) as a Resource of another application and to extract it at runtime. [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4221/Adding-and-extracting-binary-resources) one of the many available samples on the web.

Comment: thanks for your reply.
But how about the behaviour in ActiveX control?
how to load it into memory?

Comment: As you would do for a "standard" library...in Win32 it would be LoadLibraryEx(..) (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684179(v=vs.85).aspx)